# How can i custom OpenAM authentication?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openam

I need to combine LDAP and MYSQL database for authentication.
I mean, in case the username consist of specific pattern (for example ****@Google.com), authenticate against LDAP, else against MYSQL.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

You could just use OpenAM auth-chaining (LDAP + JDBC auth module in the chain) with shared state behavior. OpenAM will then traverse the modules based on your configuration. https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/13/admin-guide#configure-authn-chains